# Cannot update during an existing state transition bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Could anybody please help me?
Im getting this error in console when Im trying to navigate to PostScreen when there are no categories left to show :

**Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { View, TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground, Dimensions } from "react-native"
import { FlatGrid } from 'react-native-super-grid';
import { Text } from 'react-native-elements';
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { uniqBy } from "lodash";
import mainScreenStyles from "../styles/mainScreenStyles";
import { Badge, Avatar, Icon, Button } from "react-native-elements";


const MainScreen = props => {
    const userDisplayName = useSelector(state => state.userInfo.user_display_name)
    const categories = useSelector(state => state.categoryData)
    const [currentCategory, setCurrentCategory] = useState({ parent: 0, id: 0 });
    const [items, setItems] = useState(uniqBy(categories.filter(category => category.parent == currentCategory.parent && category.name !== "Nezaradené"), category => category.name));

    const handleChangeFilters = props => {
        setCurrentCategory({ parent: props.parent, id: props.id })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setItems(uniqBy(categories.filter(category => category.parent == currentCategory.id && category.name !== "Nezaradené"), category => category.name))
    }, [currentCategory])


    return (
        <View style={{ height: currentCategory.id == 0 ? Dimensions.get("window").height / 1.3 : Dimensions.get("window").height, backgroundColor: "white" }}>
            {currentCategory.id == 0 ? <Text style={mainScreenStyles.heading}>Vitaj, {userDisplayName}</Text> : null}
            {items.length === 0 ? props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: "PostScreen" }) :
                <FlatGrid
                    itemDimension={130}
                    data={items}
                    style={mainScreenStyles.gridView}
                    spacing={10}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
```

i think the problem is here

```
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={item.name == "Administratívno-Logistická časť" ? mainScreenStyles.itemContainerBlue : mainScreenStyles.itemContainerRed}
                            onPress={handleChangeFilters.bind(this, item)}>
                            < ImageBackground
                                resizeMode="contain"
                                source={item.name == "Administratívno-Logistická časť" ? require("../assets/icons/icon2.png") : require("../assets/icons/icon.png")}
                                style={{ height: "100%", justifyContent: 'center', }} >
                                <Text style={mainScreenStyles.itemText}>{item.name}</Text>
                            </ImageBackground>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
```

```
                    )
                    }
                />}
            {
                currentCategory.id == 0 ?

                    <TouchableOpacity style={mainScreenStyles.newPosts} onPress={() => { console.log("153") }}>
                        <Badge value="Nové" status="error" containerStyle={{ position: 'absolute', top: 8, left: 8 }} />
                        < ImageBackground resizeMode="contain" source={require("../assets/icons/quote.png")} style={{ height: "100%" }} >
                            <View style={mainScreenStyles.newPost}>
                                <View style={mainScreenStyles.newPostTopInfo}>
                                    <View>
                                        <Avatar
                                            rounded
                                            size={50}
                                            source={require("../assets/icons/profil.png")}
                                        />
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={mainScreenStyles.newPostNameAndDate} >
                                        <Text style={mainScreenStyles.newPostHeading}>Meno</Text>
                                        <Text>{Date.now()}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View>
                                        <Icon
                                            name='heart-outline'
                                            type='ionicon'
                                        />
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                                <View style={mainScreenStyles.newPostContent}>
                                    <Text style={mainScreenStyles.newPostHeading}>Lorem ipsum</Text>
                                    <Text>Lorem mLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</Text>
                                </View>
                                <View style={mainScreenStyles.buttonContainer}>
                                    <Button
                                        title="Solid Button"
                                        iconRight
                                        buttonStyle={mainScreenStyles.button}
                                        icon={
                                            <Icon
                                                name="arrow-right"
                                                size={15}
                                                color="white"
                                            />
                                        }
                                    />
                                </View>
                            </View>

                        </ImageBackground>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    : null
            }
        </View >
    )
}


export default MainScreen
```

Comment: Is there a stacktrace? This error usually happens when calling the setter of a `useState` (e.g. `setItems` in your code) while rendering is happening (e.g. synchronously inside your component). Is there a stacktrace pointing at a certain location?

Comment: yes, here it is:

Comment: at node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:471:2 in Component.prototype.setState
at http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:165745:26 in <unknown>
at node_modules/react-navigation/node_modules/@react-navigation/core/lib/module/getChildNavigation.js:44:34 in actionHelpers.actionName
at screens/MainScreen.js:28:39 in MainScreen
at [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Comment: Ah I didn't spot the `navigate` bit, which modifies `react-navigation`'s router state. Like my answer says: either call `navigate` at another time, not during rendering, or replace it with the `Redirect` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `props.navigation.navigate()` within your render code. Either move it "outside" by putting it in a `useEffect/setTimeout`, or better, use `react-navigation`'s `Redirect` component. That component is perfect for use cases like this.